# Pass a function to a constructor

Tags: c#, methods, constructor

If I have few variables which I need to pass to a constructor, but do not want to pass them separately, instead of passing them via a function/method to a constructor. Is it possible? Could you bring an example of syntax?

e.g.

```
string name_edit;
string surname_edit;
string phone_edit;
string email_edit;

private void EditContact()
{
    EditedContactDetails();
    SecondaryForm EditContactForm = new SecondaryForm(false, name_edit, surname_edit, phone_edit, email_edit);
    EditContactForm.testForm = this;
    if (EditContactForm.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        fillTheList();
    }
}
```

I want to pass `name_edit, surname_edit, phone_edit, email_edit` for example like this:

```
prWindow(Contact);
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. If you have a lot of constructor parameters maybe you should consider creating a POCO class and sending that class instance instead?

Comment: Confusing question without code

Comment: Have you considering using IOC example like unity or mef instead.

Comment: If you need threadsave variables you can get them lazy using Singletons.

Comment: Create a container class.

Comment: @CloudyMarible which will have her [own constructor](http://i.imgur.com/o1Wxcql.jpg)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them in a class:

```
class Contact
{
   public string name_edit {get; set;}
   public string surname_edit {get; set;}
   public string phone_edit {get; set;}
   public string email_edit {get; set;}
}
```

and modify the constructor of `SecondaryForm` in order to accept a `Contact` parameter:

```
public SecondaryForm (Contact contact)
{
   ...
}
```